# gcc linker library search order; paths plus static vs shared

Tags: c++, gcc, linker, operator-precedence

Reading through the gcc manual, I believe the following two statements are true:

1. Library search paths specified on the command line are searched before "default" paths (which I assume means stuff in the LIBRARY_PATH environment variable)
2. Shared libraries will be linked in preference to static libraries (in the absence of flags saying to do otherwise)

But which of these two dominates? For example, if I type

```
gcc myprog.cpp -o myprog -Lmypath -lmylibrary
```

and in mypath there is the static library "libmylibrary.a", and in some place specified in LIBRARY_PATH there is a shared library "libmylibrary.so", which of these libraries will get used? My guess would be that the static library will get used (i.e. (1) dominates) but I am seeing some funny compile errors that make me question this guess, so I wanted to make sure...

Comment: Make sure that `-lmylibrary` appears after your `.o` (or `.c`) files.

Comment: Ahh yes, sorry, it is, I'll make a more correct example.

Comment: Quick tip: You can get gcc to list the actual paths with `g++ -E -x c++ - -v < /dev/null` Other than that, I think I've seen this question being answered here before, including how to override the default behavior by specifying the full name of the library (w/`.a`/`.so` extension).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your example, the static library  `libmylibrary.a` will be linked in
preference to any `libmylibrary.a` or `libmylibrary.so` that might
exist in one of the linker's default search directories. The linker
searchs in `mypath` before any of the default places, and as soon as
it finds a `libmylibrary.a` or `libmylibrary.so`, it looks no further
to satisfy `-lmylibrary`.

If `mypath` contained *both* `libmylibrary.a` and `libmylibrary.so`, the
latter would be preferred.

I am not sure what source you are referring to by "the gcc manual", but
"the gcc linker" is the GNU linker, `ld`, and you will find the
meanings of the commandline options very well explained in its [manual](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/ld/Invocation.html#Invocation)

Comment: Sorry yes I was talking about the man page for ld, as you have linked to (although yours has a little more detail than the one on my system) The section on the "-L" flag gave me statement (1), and the section on "-l" gave me statement (2). But even in the page you link to it is not clear to me that the ambiguity I raise is covered. But anyway what you says makes sense so I'll accept the answer :). Unless some debate emerges :p.

Comment: Actually maybe the part on "-l" does technically cover it, since it says "ld will search **a directory** for a library called libnamespec.so before searching for one called libnamespec.a.", i.e. it will only prefer shared libraries while searching in a single directory. But still, it is nice to have it said a little more explicitly so thanks :).